# Check if Two Arrays Sorted in Decreasing and Increasing Order Satisfy a Condition

Tags: arrays, permutations

Given 2 arrays $A, B$ each of size $n$. If we want to find if the two arrays satisfy the condition that $A[i] + B[i] \ge k$ for all indices $i$, it's sufficient to fulfill 3 conditions below:

1. Sum of all elements of $A$ and $B$ is $\ge nk$
2. Sum of max element of $A$ and min element of $B$ is $\ge k$ (edge case)
3. Sum of min element of $A$ and max element of $B$ is $\ge k$ (edge case)

**Edit**: Based on answers, these 3 conditions are not sufficient to prove that they work with all cases please given that they don't go over elements in between edge cases?

Comment: I just realized that this question can be considered about math only, even if there is a flavor of algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these 3 conditions are not sufficient.

For example, $n=4$, $A=[6,5,2,1]$, $B=[1,3,4,6]$, $k=7$.

- The sum of all elements in $A$ and $B$ is $14+14=28=4\cdot7$.
- The sum of the max in $A$ and the min in $B$ is $7$.
- The sum of the min in $A$ and the max in $B$ is $7$.

However, $A[2]+B[2]=2+4=6<7$.

Comment: This is indeed a solution to a hackerrank problem "Permuting Two Arrays" and it works for all cases! It's weird.

Comment: Another example. $n=5$, $\ A=[100,4,3,2,1]$, $\ B=[1,2,3,4,100]$, $\ k=44$. We have $A[i]+B[i]<44$ for all $i$ except the required cases $i=0,4$.

Comment: @Avv Where are the problem and that solution on HackerRank?

Comment: Here is the solution link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-arrays/forum/comments/1254159. If you submit it, it will work with all cases.

Comment: @Avv their testcases are clearly insufficient (or incorrectly created) and the proposed solution fails on a small counterexamples provided here. You should probably write to the problem author https://www.hackerrank.com/profile/Khongor rather than here. Your original post should probably be modified to ask "are these three conditions sufficient..." rather than asking "why are these three conditions sufficient..."

Comment: @JimN. I did that